# Image button hide and un-hide

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a image button in my gridview that is named StopImageButton and StartImageButton

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stop">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="StopImageButton" runat="server" OnClick="StopImageButton_Click"
                          ImageUrl="~/Stop.jpg" Width="25" Height="25" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="StartImageButton" runat="server" OnClick="StartImageButton_Click"  
                           ImageUrl="~/Start.jpg" Width="25" Height="25" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I also have this code that hides the `StopImageButton` when the page loads

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton ImgBtn = e.Row.FindControl("StopImageButton") as ImageButton;
        ImgBtn.Visible = false;
    }

}

protected void StopImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void StartImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

}
```

What I want to do is, After Clicking the `StartImageButton`, It will be hidden, and the  `StopImageButton` will now be then visible? Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void StartImageButton_Click(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //hide StartImageButton
    ImageButton StartBtn = e.Row.FindControl("StartImageButton") as ImageButton;
    StartBtn.Visible = false;

    //UnHide StopImageButton
    ImageButton StopBtn = e.Row.FindControl("StopImageButton") as ImageButton;
    StopBtn.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Row.FindControl is not applicable to ImageClickEventArgs

Comment: My mistake ! You need to pass `GridViewRowEventArgs` I've edited

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    protected void StartImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton StartImageButton = (ImageButton)sender;
        StartImageButton.Visible = false;
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)StartImageButton.Parent.Parent;
        ImageButton StopImageButton = (ImageButton)gr.FindControl("StopImageButton");
        StopImageButton.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: `StartImageButton.Visible = true; // should be false.`